# Spring XD Rest api job launch with jobParameters responding with 'jobParameters' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: spring-xd

I have Spring XD job already deployed which expects 2 `jobParameter`s (`absoluteFilePath` and `fileName`). Actually this job is triggered by JMS stream whose output provides those 2 `jobParameter`s in JSON format and that works fine. I want to launch the job with REST API like:

```
curl -X POST   http://localhost:9393/jobs/executions?jobname=loadData&jobParameters=%7B%22absoluteFilePath%22%3A%22C%3A%2FUB%2Fdev%2FBM.txt%22%2C%22fileName%22%3A%22BM.txt%22%7D
```

*Error I'm getting:
'jobParameters' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

Wondering if there is anything wrong with CURL command or if `jobParameters` is not supported?

I'm able to launch a job without `jobParameter`s with the following CURL command, but as the job expects parameters it fails.

```
curl -X POST   http://localhost:9393/jobs/executions?jobname=loadData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried launching via the XD shell? It sends the `jobName` and `jobParameters` in the request body...

```
public void launchJob(String name, String jobParameters) {
    String uriTemplate = resources.get("jobs/executions").toString();
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> values = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    values.add("jobParameters", jobParameters);
    values.add("jobname", name);
    restTemplate.postForObject(uriTemplate, values, Object.class);
}
```

This looks like an OS shell message; try adding '...' around the URL.

Google makes me think this is on Windows (not sure where you're getting curl from); for Windows, you'll probably need "...".

(The problem is the `&`).

Comment: Edited - looks like an OS shell/cmd issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for help. It also works from shell