# Launch a batch job based on Json Parameter in Spring-XD

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-xd

I assume that this is not possible as it is not listed in the XD documentation.

What I am looking for is a way to launch a job dynamically from a RabbitMQ message that contains the jobName in the payload. This would allow me to have a single job queue where all my jobs are sent rather than having to have a separate queue of each job.

```
{
   jobName:"myJob",
   jobParm1: "parm1",
   jobParm2: "parm2"
}
```

This would allow me to have a single job queue where all my jobs are sent rather than having to have a separate queue of each job.

[This post shows that is possible using http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971057/spring-xd-rest-api-job-launch-with-jobparameters-responding-with-jobparameters)

Answer (score 1):

You could construct an XD stream the reads from rabbit, transforms the payload and invokes the http-client processor (dumping the output the `null` or `log` sink).